# docker --volumes-from not mounting any files

Tags: docker, glusterfs

I have two containers that in one of them I am using gluster file system to mount the files that I need into mnt directory of my container and I'm using `VOLUME /mnt`  in my Dockerfile to share the volume.
I run this container with this:

```
docker run -d --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device=/dev/fuse:/dev/fuse -e MOUNTPOINT="server1:test" -e TARGET="/mnt"  --name gluster gluster-client
```

and I want to use this files in the second container that is a nginx container so I run this container using --volumes-from to use that shared volume, this is how I run my container:

```
docker run -it --volumes-from gluster  nginx sh
```

my gluster container works fine, I mean I checked the mount directory(here /mnt) and I can see the files, but in second container that I'm usig docker --volumes-from there's no files in /mnt directory, it seems that it can mount the directory but not the files inside those directories,how can I fix it?, is it because I am using gluster or what?

gluster container is based on fedora and nginx container is based on alpine.

I appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to SELinux. Try running the second container as

```
docker run -it --volumes-from gluster:z  nginx sh
```

From [docker run reference documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volumes-from-container-volumes-from):

> Labeling systems like SELinux require that proper labels are placed on
>   volume content mounted into a container. Without a label, the security
>   system might prevent the processes running inside the container from
>   using the content. By default, Docker does not change the labels set
>   by the OS.
>
> To change the label in the container context, you can add either of
>   two suffixes :z or :Z to the volume mount. These suffixes tell Docker
>   to relabel file objects on the shared volumes. The z option tells
>   Docker that two containers share the volume content. As a result,
>   Docker labels the content with a shared content label. Shared volume
>   labels allow all containers to read/write content. The Z option tells
>   Docker to label the content with a private unshared label. Only the
>   current container can use a private volume.

About the same argument you can find more details on [Using Volumes with Docker can Cause Problems with SELinux](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/) and [Practical SELinux and Containers](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/dwalsh_selinux_containers/).

EDIT:
If that is not the reason, your problem should due to glusterfs and data container. Try using named volumes.

Change the `VOLUME` line in first container to

```
VOLUME myVolume:/mnt
```

and in the second container, instead of `--volumes-from`, you can use `--volume=myVolume`.

See more on data container and named volumes on [Docker Data Containers and Named Volumes](https://boxboat.com/2016/06/18/docker-data-containers-and-named-volumes/) and [Docker named volume explained](https://madcoda.com/2016/03/docker-named-volume-explained/).

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't fix my problem unfortunately!

Comment: Edited answer after your comment.

Comment: I tried the named volumes too but it didn't make any difference, so until I find a solution I am mounting the glusterfs files on local and using this local files in my nginx container.